# What are equivalent to a sequence of normed bounded linear operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $T_n\in B(X,Y)$, $n=1, 2, ...$, show that equivalent statements are:
>
> (a) $(||T_n||)$ is bounded
>
> (b) $(||T_nx||)$ is bounded for all $x\in X$
>
> (c) $(|g(T_nx)|)$ is bounded for all $x\in X$ and all $g\in Y'$

All I have got is (b)$\rightarrow$(a) by the Uniform Boundedness Theorem. Any hints or solutions would be helpful.

Comment: (b)$\to$ (a) IS the uniform boundedness theorem

Answer (score 0):

(a)->(c): for each $g\in Y'$ and $x\in X$ we have $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: |g(T_n x)|\leq ||g||\cdot ||T_n x||\leq ||g||\cdot ||T_n||\cdot ||x||\leq ||g||\cdot C\cdot ||x||,$$ if $||T_n||\leq C$ for each $n$.

(c)->(b): this is in fact again the uniform boundedness theorem, applied to the family $\{\iota(T_n x): x\in X, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where $\iota$ denotes the canonical isometric embedding $Y\to Y''$, i.e. $\iota(y)(g)=g(y)$. (c) means that this family is pointwise bounded, therefore uniformly bounded. Since $\iota$ is isometric, we obtain (b).

Hope that helps!

EDIT: My argument from (c)->(b) can be generalized to obtain that a set $A\subseteq Y$ is norm-bounded iff $g(A)$ is a bounded subset of the complex field for each $g\in Y'$. This usually is denoted by the phrase "strongly bounded iff weakly bounded".